# Compact way to make a Variable non-copyable

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a couple classes in my code, of which I need to copy objects.

However, some of those classes use data which I would like to skip when copying, like owner pointers.

So far, the only way I've found of doing this either to avoid copying entirely and construct a completely new object by hand every time I need to copy one, or wrapping the owner pointer in a private, non-copyable struct, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    // non-copyable owner
    struct Owner {
        Owner() = default;
        ~Owner() = default;

        Owner(const Owner& o) = delete;
        Owner& operator=(const Owner& o) = delete;

        SomeOtherClass* pointer = nullptr;
    };

    Owner owner = Owner();
}
```

However, doing it this way seems a little verbose.

(Note I would not like to use `std::unique_ptr` as I do not wish to deconstruct the owner when the object is deconstructed)

Is there a more compact / efficient / readable way of doing this?

Edit: the invalidating of `default` marked constructors etc. stemmed from me not initializing owner with a default value. Silly.

EDIT 2: Perhaps I should clear some things up: The owner pointer should point to the object that owns the `MyClass`, as a way for the owned object to refer to its owner. Not the other way around. That is why I wish to not copy the pointer, as an object with a different owner that is supposed to copy this object should not change which object it is owned by.

The accepted answer enables me to do just that. I hope this cleared up some of the confusion.

Comment: Do you want a compiler error when someone tries to copy your struct like a=b or you want it be moved instead of copied?

Comment: For the `Owner`, yes. But not for the `MyClass`. Calling `MyClass a; MyClass b; a = b` should invoke the `operator=` which I either have to write manually or mark `default`, if possible.

Comment: Then is a factory method instead of a field, ok for you? Since it can't assign to a rvalue but still you can access it, and it produces once accordingly to its own parent object. Probably with a uid? First access creates it, second access uses it. But it may need some more pointer logic which makes it not efficient/readable enough.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you have in mind, could you provide an example?

Comment: What does “skip when copying” mean?  Do you want a memberwise copy of the overall object but with some subobjects default-initialized?

Comment: Very confused about what you want. You say in a comment you want `MyClass` assignment to compile, but it won't given the code shown. Maybe add a few example uses of `MyClass` (and/or `MyClass::Owner`, if it's not really supposed to be private) and describe what behavior you want from each?

Comment: **Obviously**, `MyClass` cannot have default copy if it contains a member that it not copiable. As far as I know, the recommandation is to explicitly delete copy and move constructor and assignment operator if you don't want accidental copy or move. So you would have 4 lines instead of 2. It is possible to be shorter by preventing copy indirectly but it is less readable. Also most editors have a copy and paste command so it is not that much hard to wrote these 4 lines.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to do what you want.  Can you provide an actual working example of what you want?  When you copy class containing a non-copyable field, what happens to the field in the original and in the copy?  How about move?  What happens if you return such an object from a function or pass it by value?  What about elision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `std::unique_ptr` with a deleter that does nothing.

```
template<typename T>
struct nop_deleter<T> {void operator()(T*){};};

class MyClass {
  std::unique_ptr<SomeType, nop_deleter<SomeType>> owner;
};
```

The "owned" object will then not be deconstructed. (At this point it's not really *owned* anymore, but that's just me being pedantic).

If you want it to be a tad more readable you can always alias the type:

```
template<typename T>
struct nop_deleter<T> {void operator()(T*){};};

template<typename T>
using Owner = std::unique_ptr<T, nop_deleter<T>>;

class MyClass {
  Owner<SomeType> owner;
};
```

Comment: This will move ownership from the source when you std move, and not permit copying of the class that contains it.  It seems exactly what the OP doesn't want?

Comment: @Yakk I'm considering the example as the *de facto* semantics the OP wants. Also, "move ownership" isn't really what's happening here, since the container class has no responsibility for releasing the resource, i.e: it doesn't really own it. Finally, no one should really care about what happens to the moved-from object, as move semantics dictate that it may be left in a *valid but unspecified state*.

Comment: @Yakk having said that, I agree with yout that it's not great program design. Your answer is much better than this one, in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Copy (and move) have required semantics due to how elision works, and to a lesser degree how containers work.

Well behaved value types shouldn't behave surprisingly differently if a copy or move is elided.  They should also behave well when stored in a `std::vector`.

Your description seems a lot like how `auto_ptr` was hacked into being a `unique_ptr` before we had language support for moving.  It was a clever idea that turned into a monster of a bad one, and `auto_ptr` is one of the few deprecated features of the standard library because of how much of a bad idea it turned out to be.

Split the "state" of your types from its identity.  Ownership is an identity feature, for example, while height is a state feature.

Store the state in a `struct` within your type.

The identity either store within your type, or in another substruct.  The identity substruct should have `=delete` copy/move operations.

Provide a way to create a new object with a new identity but the same state.  If the object type is Foo, and its state is FooState, then you'd have a `Foo(FooState)` explicit constructor.

Have a method that produces a state-wise copy of a `Foo`.

Do not permit `Foo` to be copied.  The semantics of copying a `Foo` where the identity changes (is cleared) after a copy are *not healthy copy semantics*.  A `Foo` should be non-copyable.

Move semantics are possible; in such a case, you'd report to your owner(s) that your location is changing (through some interface) -- like:

```
if (owner)
  owner->child_moving( &old, this );
for( auto* child:children )
  child->parent_moving( &old, this );
```

which permits parent/children to update their owner/child pointers.

Unless you do that kind of thing, you don't want to pretend to have value semantics; delete your copy/move operations instead of implementing insane ones.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like a factory method at least evades the copying part in compile time?

```
// a method of MyClass
Owner * MyOwner()
{
     // check if created
     if(uidMap.find(parentObjectUid )==uidMap.end())
     {
         // create if needed
         uidMap.insert(std::pair<size_t,Owner *>(parentObjectUid ,new Owner()));
         // you can even use shared/unique ptr instead of new Owner()
         //    if you want automatic garbage
         return uidMap[parentObjectUid ];

     }
     else
     {
          return uidMap[parentObjectUid];
     }
}
```

then creating uid may need an unwanted singletone or similar global synchronized production. So as long as MyClass is copied with same uid, both copies will have same single object of Owner.

```
MyClass a;
MyClass b;
Owner * o = a.MyOwner(); // => creates
Owner * p = a.MyOwner(); // => uses
Owner * q = b.MyOwner(); // => creates another
a = b; // doesn't copy anything Owner
```

a unique id could be an incremented 64bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

An owner that does not own the resource? Sounds like you are lying in your code, if I would see this in code, I would think you have a bug.

That said, unique_ptr is really the best way of dealing with it. You could give it a custom destructor to do the closing of the resource (like closing a file handle). From a readable perspective, this will be the easiest to understand instead of having your custom class.

I don't know how you define efficient, however, assuming runtime efficiency, their ain't any effect.

The most compact way of writing will be inheriting from a NonCopyable class, boost has one, however it is very easy to write if you don't want that dependency.

From the readable perspective, I actually would go with a variation  of your orginal implementation, which is: follow the rule of 5: specify Ctor, copy Ctor, move ctor, copy assign and move assign in your class.